# Missing coverage results for Dotcover in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, dotcover, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am able to generate the HTML reports with the help of DotCover and passing the same to Sonarqube using "/d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=.\dotCover\dotCoverResults.html" (dotcover html has coverage data in it). In Sonar log I do not see any error message but Sonar dashboard shows no coverage; it is blank. Similar configuration for another application is working perfectly fine in other application but not in this. Blow is the configuration used in Jenkins for this.

Sonarqube version: 4.5.7
MSBuild SonarQube Runner: 2.0
C#: 5.2

```
dotnet restore --configfile .\.nuget\NuGet.Config
MSBuild myApplication.sln /t:Clean /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64
nunit3-console.exe test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\net461\UnitTests.dll --result=nunit-test-results.xml;format=nunit2 --labels=On
dotCover.exe analyse .\dotCover\coverageDebug.xml
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Coc, I am getting the same. It would be great if you resolved this.